# Video does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, react-hooks, jsx

I'm trying to format a video depending on the view type.

I have 2 video elements that alternate depending on the view.

This is just a brief explanation of what I'm trying to do, I cannot do conditional classnames because different both views have different components

```
const videoRef = useRef();
```

The src is set in a useEffect that runs once like such

```
useEffect(() => {
    videoRef.current.srcObject = address;
},[]);
```

In the component, I am returning

```
return(
{viewType ? 
    <video classname={classes.downtop} ref={videoRef} /> 
    : <video classname={classes.topdown} ref={videoRef} /> }
);
```

viewType is a boolean as seen below, as there's only 2 view types

```
const [viewType, setViewType] = useState(true);
```

to change the view type I simply call the

```
setViewType(false);
```

The problem I'm getting is that at first It shows the video for downtop, but when i change the value of view type the video doesn't show.

I'm not too sure how to fix this. If someone could help that be great

Comment: What are you changing `viewType` to?

Comment: _"I can do conditional classnames because different both views have different components"_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: Sorry I meant cannot, it has been updated to be clear. Hope you understand now

Comment: OK, but the only difference between the two sides of your condition at the end is the `className` prop, so the only effect of the condition is to change the `className`. Is this example maybe a simplification of your actual code? I ask because the code we don't see could be relevant to the problem.